# What is the minimum draw size for a line?

Tags: c#, wpf

I read that wpf programs can draw lines in between pixels and then it displays .5 the line on one pixel and .5 the line on the other pixel. Does this mean that there is no actual limit on how small of a line I can draw except as limited by hardware?

Comment: Remember there's a *zoom* setting too..

Comment: well a one pixel line isn't exactly a line...

Comment: A line between a point and itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF uses `double` to represent all the geometric properties (like the length of a line). When it comes to actually outputting to the screen these will obviously be rounded to pixels but this happens right down at the core level. As far as you, as the programmer, need to know, you can design lines of any length between `double.MinValue` and `double.MaxValue` (±1.8E+308)

Comment: does each pixel just take the average value of the line's crossing it? because I read that the line does not have to snap to pixel, so that means that half of the line is on one pixel and half is on another pixel...so does that mean that both of the pixels will have half the intensity of the colored lines that partially pass through the pixel?

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet Yes! Both pixels will have some of the line on them. Exactly what amount (whether it's half the intensity or otherwise) is affected by many things including the stroke. This is quite easy to see when drawing a number of parallel lines with a width of 1: those that are on pixels (have a position of n-0.5 due to WPF using the centre as a reference) look sharper and darker than those which are off-pixel.
If you need the line to be on pixels you can use the [UIElement.SnapToDevicePixels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.maxvalue.aspx) property.